# Does XForms have a successor?

Tags: xforms

We are looking for a desktop forms technology with an easy to use (read non technical) authoring environment. When I last looked at this, some years back, it seemed that XForms would mature in to something really useful. Now there appears to be little happening with the technology (only 5 questions under the XForms tag here for instance) and not much offered in the way of tools, especially desktop based ones.

So, is XForms dead? Has something better come along?

Comment: IBM has a lot of useful and non technical XForms stuff, although perhaps a bit "enterprisy". See e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/forms/demos.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a lot of [software which supports XForms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms). I used it for a project a couple years ago, and I was impressed by the amount of work done by very little code. The W3C does not advertise their technologies to PHBs, so adoption is bound to be slow while others are pushing buzzword-compliant vendor specific solutions as panacea. There's also stigma among developers (especially those who consider themselves "hard core", it seems) against what is seen as a pointless "XML-ization" of everything in computer science. Also, the side track into HTML 5 I believe is taking the focus away from the more interesting issues on the web.

Comment: http://google.com/trends?q=xforms <- not looking too good. XForms implementation was denied by most browsers and thus it became a backend technology. It's sad, because it had the potential to really cleanup html forms, data binding, etc.

Comment: So is XML, and even just 'forms' (more surprisingly) search volumes falling.  Compare JSON (and HTML5), no surprises there. http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=xforms%2C%20forms%2C%20html5%2C%20xml%2C%20json&cmpt=q

Answer (score 5):

It's probably blasphemy to call it successor, but forms are being worked on in HTML5 (it all started as "Web Forms 2.0").

It's not more advanced than XForms, but answers "what happened to XForms".

Answer (score 4):

We are currently reviewing XForms for a project.  There are several small, active projects previously mentioned, although Ubiquity has been merged into [backplanejs](https://code.google.com/p/backplanejs/), and that appears moribund.

[Orbeon](http://www.orbeon.com/) is certainly actively developing and releasing new versions, and slowly adding features from XForms 2.0 standard.  From an external point of view, they appear to be the healthiest and are LGPL/commercial.  They are not a pure client solution, though, as there is a server component.

[BetterFORM](http://betterform.de/en/index.html) is also actively developing and releasing new versions, and their solution is pure client-side for XForms.

There are a couple of small projects that look interesting: [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms) seems to be the liveliest and is 100% browser-based; there's a dual license LGPL/commercial.

In my opinion, it's a great technology but it's also a niche technology.  The ability to "externalize" chunks of your user interface is extremely useful (especially in my company's application), but it doesn't result in UIs that are as good as the best HTML5 UIs.

I do not know whether client-only XForms support is the best approach in an age of apps and mobile devices.  I do know that I'd like to see a product that produced UIs compatible with popular Javascript frameworks like extjs to simplify inclusion of XForms into an existing UI.

If you need it, it's out there, but it doesn't look like it will ever be big.

Comment: Eclipse has announced EMF Forms in the latest version of Eclipse -- this is well-suited to desktop app development if you're OK with Java-based applications.  A successor?  Time will tell.

Comment: Pure client-side xforms is 'dangerous'...  See https://betterform.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/why-client-side-xforms-is-not-enough/ and BetterFORM is a mixed solution. Some processing takes place on the client, some in the server, just like with Orbeon, but they are always in sync and hard to mislead.

BetterFORM uses lots of javascript from DOJO and they are advancing, but if I find the time somewhere, I'd like to get a kind of JSF based solution. Integrating best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3):

XForms has to be implemented at client-side to be publicly used. There are two projects for a free client-side implementation without plug-in nor install : Ubiquity XForms and XSLTForms (http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms)

Answer (score 1):

XForms is [officially dead](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms):

> The Forms Working Group was officially closed on 2015-04-08

If you're looking for forms that don't do a ton of dynamic stuff, [HTML 5 forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) have some built-in validation features.

If you want forms that do a lot of dynamic, interesting stuff, JavaScript is probably the right tool for the job.

You can still use XForms if you want. [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.htm) use JavaScript under the hood to let you write XForms in the browser and have it just work. Try doing view-source here: http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms/spreadsheet.xml. The source is pure XML.

[eXistdb](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html) bundles XForms and other XML stuff for full-stack XML development.

Answer (score -2):

As of 2014, XForms seems to be a dead standard.

Comment: Not dead -- there are still several active participants (as of early 2015) in the W3C working group -- but it's definitely not a hot topic.  January had 22 messages, but as of early February, the only traffic has been various "regrets" messages -- meetings are still being held on a regular basis with a few exceptions.